# find all words which contain present characters

Tags: regex

I have a group of characters eg: `(?=a,b,c)`.

Task is to match all words in the list which contain one or more of all of this char's

Comment: Okay! Wish you good luck

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. And that probably has been answered before.

Comment: the question changed completely , i second ago you asked  to match one  or more occurrence of    (?=a,b,c)

Comment: what do you want to match??`a`,`b` and `c` at least once?

Comment: yes, but answer present below explain me everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go , this should do it for you .

```
 ^([\(]*)+([\?]*)+([=]*)+([a]*)+([,]*)+([b]*)+([,]*)+([c]*)+([\)]*)
```

passed below test cases :

```
(?=aa,b,c)
(?=aa,b,c)))))))
(?=aa,bb,cccccc)
(??===aa,b,c)
```

test from terminal>

> za$ test_str="(?=aa,b,c)" ; if [[ $test_str =~ 
>   ^([(]*)+([\?]*)+([=]*)+([a]*)+([,]*)+([b]*)+([,]*)+([c]*)+([)]*) ]]
>   ; then echo "passed" ; fi

I hope this help.